# Swapping two divs with jQuery while maintaining bound event handlers

Tags: jquery, html, swap, attr

I have two divs, #content and #contentSwap. I am loading some data into #contentSwap, performing a few operations on it, and then swapping it with #content. I was using the html() function to swap the two, but I just realized that this was causing a problem: the functions I was assigning to anchors in #contentSwap with click() were getting lost. Here is an example of the code:

```
$('#contentSwap').html(data);

$('#contentSwap a').each(function(){
 $(this).click(function(){
  // Do whatever
 });
});

$('#content').html($('#contentSwap').html());
$('#contentSwap').html("");
```

The function assigned with click() doesn't work in #content after this.

However, if I use the attr() function to modify the id of each div the click() functions stick around. But this doesn't work every time, and causes all kinds of bugs including multiple copies of #content and #contentSwap etc. Here is the code for that:

```
$('#content').attr("id", "contentSwap1");
$('#contentSwap').attr("id", "content");
$('#contentSwap1').attr("id", "contentSwap");
$('#contentSwap').html("");
```

How can I swap #content and #contentSwap effectively without losing the click() functions I've assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it is you are trying to do, but a click handler assigned to `#contentSwap` will not suddenly start working for `#content`.

If your not using the `#contentSwap` element for something else later, you could just move the entire element inside `#content`, and use a delegated event handler to make sure it works, something like:

```
$('#contentSwap').html(data);

$('#contentSwap a').each(function(){
   $(document).on('click', this, function(){
       //document should be replace with nearest non dynamic parent
       //do your thing
   });
});

$('#content').empty().append($('#contentSwap'));
```

Comment: Figured this one out! The second block of code I provided WAS working, but the #contentSwap div wasn't in the same place as the #content div. I moved it into the right space and it works great now.

Comment: I'm guessing you're a MooTools developer:)

Comment: @gdoron - How exactly would that help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is:

```
$('#contentSwap').contents().appendTo('#content');
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jHSwY/

[`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) is used to get every child (including text nodes) of `#contentSwap`. The children are then moved inside `#content`, using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) (see the sentence containing "it will be moved into the target").

Comment: This would probably work too, but I already got it. Good tip.

Answer (score 0):

This is called event delegation. Basically, you are programatically/dynamically generating that content, so the default event binding no longer works.
`.live` is deprecated but you can use:

```
 $(#contentSwap a).on("click", function(){
  // Do whatever
 });
```

Also, that `each` function doesn't seem to be doing anything and I'm fairly sure you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out! The second block of code I provided WAS working, but the #contentSwap div wasn't in the same place as the #content div. I moved it into the right space and everything turned out great.

http://www.tylergerard.com